# Swagger Api authorization key?

Tags: c#, html, rest, api, swagger

I'm trying to authorize to an open source Swagger environment, but I need to have access to it without limitations. After 3600 ms, my key gets expired. I'm wondering if someone has a solution to this...

I would be really happy if someone can give me an advice and help me out. Since I have tried for hours... Actually I get the key easily by Postman but I'm trying to automate a process with the API, since the API key expires I can't do that, any known solution?

Comment: You need to refresh your token or increase to more than 3600ms. Read more about OAuth

Comment: Change your expiration settings based on your environment (dev vs prod). Or implement a refresh token mechanism.

Comment: @aussiejoe  Thank you so much , I searched for refresh token mechanism and found a soultion, Thanks man